# How can you translate the word "whatsoever" to spanish?

Tags: traducción

I've been struggling to find an accurate expression that translates to Spanish the word "whatsoever".

Comment: Try a postfix *alguno*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The right translation is EN LO ABSOLUTO.  That is, to give emphasis.

Answer (score 11):

I think it depends on the context.  In many contexts, *whatsoever* adds emphasis to *any*.
"I don't really care for any style of architecture whatsoever."

In that context, I would use "cualquiera" or "cualesquiera" as translating both the "any" and the "whatsoever".

http://blog.lengua-e.com/2008/cualquier-cualquiera-cualesquiera/

But you have to be careful.  In a lot of phrases, these two words carry an overtone of mediocrity.  That might not be what you are trying to express.

Comment: +1 I would say cualesquiera is quite good for this case. Nevertheless be careful on its use.

Answer (score 7):

As Walter says, it depends on the context, and it's mostly an issue of emphasis.
Some examples:

> If you have any information whatsoever...
> Si tienes **cualquier tipo** de información...
> Si tienes alguna información, **cualquiera que sea**,...
>
> His tactics had no consequences whatsoever.
> Sus tácticas no tuvieron **ningún tipo** de consecuencias.
>
> He cannot be of any assistance whatsoever.
> No puede ser de ayuda **de ninguna manera**.  (o "**de ningún modo**").
>
> He entertained no worldly ambition whatsoever.
> No abrigaba ambiciones mundanas de **ninguna especie** (o "**de ningún tipo**").
>
> There is no justification whatsoever for that
> No hay **ningún tipo** de justificación para eso.
> No hay justificación **alguna** para eso.

(last one added as per tchrist's comment)

Comment: No hay justificación **alguna** para eso.